# How to speed up foreign key creation in MySQL for large tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, foreign-key, mysql-5.7

I am trying to set a foreign key constraint on a 5.7 InnoDB table with 30M+ rows.

It now already runs for over 1h on a quad core 64GB server. The processlist outputs the state `copy to tmp table` for the issued alter table command.

InnoDB_buffer_pool_size is set to 32G and has room. The system does not swap.

Why does the system create a tmp table and can this somehow be increased in performance?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` will make adding the foreign key creation almost instant. Note that `foreign_key_checks=OFF;` must be set before adding the foreign key.

**Example:**

```
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = OFF;

ALTER TABLE `my_schema`.`my_table` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `my_constraint`
  FOREIGN KEY (`my_column`)
  REFERENCES `my_schema`.`my_other_table` (`my_other_column`)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
  ALGORITHM = INPLACE,
  LOCK = NONE;
  
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = ON;
```

Note that this approach comes with a few [downsides](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312541/what-are-the-possible-downsides-or-consequences-of-using-algorithm-inplace-lock).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A `FOREIGN KEY`:

- Includes an index, which may help performance during `JOINs`, sometimes significantly.
- Includes a constraint that guarantees the existence of a matching row in another table.

Some cases of adding an index require copying the table over.  Hence the "copy".  Apparently, you have such a situation.  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before the command, and the `ALTER TABLE` that was adding the FK.