# What are the possible downsides or consequences of using ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE when running alters on a table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysql-8.0

I've been trying to find the answer to this online for a while with no luck.

What are possible downsides or consequences to running an alter (such as add index, add column, drop index, drop column) with `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE` in mysql 8.0 innodb?

I figure there have to be some concerns or situations where you would not want to use `LOCK=NONE` at least.

If new rows are being added to the table as you run the alter to add an index, is it possible that some indexes wouldn't be created? I'm just wondering if I should be concerned about using these for all alters I run.

Thanks

Comment: If the requested Algorithm cannot be performed, it will refuse to even start the Alter.  For example, Altering the Primary Key must be done with COPY.  Lock=NONE has some caveats (see the manual), but they may be acceptable to you.

Comment: @RickJames It depends on server SQL mode. Server may either fail the query or execute it with the warning similar to "ALGORITHM=INPLACE is not applicable, COPY is used".

Answer (score 2):

Some drawbacks of `INPLACE` algorithm are:

> 1. Long-running online DDL operations can cause replication lag in slaves. Online DDL operation must finish running on the master before
>    it is run on the slave. Also, DML that was processed concurrently on
>    the master is only processed on the slave after the DDL operation on
>    the slave is completed.
> 2. larger [innodb_online_alter_log_max_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_online_alter_log_max_size) size extends the period of time at the end of the DDL operation when
>    the table is locked to apply the data from the log.
> 3. At time can cause high IO usage for a larger table at high concurrency servers ( Aggressive in terms of resource consumption)

Check the list of [Online DDL Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-limitations.html)

Before running a DDL [operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-performance.html) on a large table, check whether the operation is fast or slow as follows:

> 1. Clone the table structure.
> 2. Populate the cloned table with a small amount of data.
> 3. Run the DDL operation on the cloned table.
> 4. Check whether the “rows affected” value is zero or not. A nonzero value means the operation copies table data, which might require
>    special planning. For example, you might do the DDL operation during a
>    period of scheduled downtime, or on each replica server one at a time.